# Removing Brackets in year of publication, and Italics in Journal name and volume

Tags: bibtex

I will like to remove the bracket in the year and the italics from the Journal name as well as the volume in my references.

Here is my code for now and the results. I am a new learner in case you feel some of the packages i used are not in the right order.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin = 1.5in, bmargin = 1 in, lmargin= 1.5 in, rmargin = 1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

This comes after all my writings.

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{master}

\end{document}
```

I saved all my references as master.bib. Some of these references are in this format

Here is a sample reference

```
@article{miura2009,
    title={Mechanism of skull suture maintenance and interdigitation},
    author={Miura, Takashi and Perlyn, Chad A and Kinboshi, Masato and Ogihara, Naomichi and Kobayashi-Miura, Mikiko and Morriss-Kay, Gillian M and Shiota, Kohei},
    journal={Journal of anatomy},
    volume={215},
    number={6},
    pages={642-655},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{pritchard1956,
    title={The structure and development of cranial and facial sutures},
    author={Pritchard, JJ and Scott, JH and Girgis, F Gt},
    journal={Journal of anatomy},
    volume={90},
    number={Pt 1},
    pages={73},
    year={1956},
    publisher={Wiley-Blackwell}
}

@article{renier2000,
    title={Management of craniosynostoses},
    author={Renier, Dominique and Lajeunie, Elizabeth and Arnaud, Eric and Marchac, Daniel},
    journal={Child's Nervous System},
    volume={16},
    number={10-11},
    pages={645-658},
    year={2000},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

> Zollikofer, C. P. and Weissmann, J. D. (2011). A bidirectional interface growth model for cranial interosseous suture morphogenesis. *Journal of anatomy,
>   219(2):100-114*.

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: You are not using the `biblatex` package, but good old BibTeX styles (`apalike.bst`). I have re-tagged your question accordingly to avoid confusion. If you want to make it easier for others to help you, consider adding the `.bib` entry of an example citation, so we don't have to re-type it. See [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)